# Access specific Gutenberg block in template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Trying to wrap my head around this. I have a page in WP and Im using the block editor. Im trying to get away from one off ACF fields and transition into using the native block editor. Usually I would create an ACF WSYWIG field, 'intro_content' and call it like

```
<?php the_field('intro_content'); ?>
```

However, I'd like to be able to target the native Gutenberg blocks. Say for example I have 4 separate paragraph blocks and I want to place the second one somewhere on the page.

I can output an array of all the blocks like this:

```
<?php
    $blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content() );
    print_r($blocks);
?>
```

Which will output this on the page

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [blockName] => core/paragraph [attrs] => Array ( [className] => foobar ) [innerBlocks] => Array ( ) [innerHTML] =>
This is P1
[innerContent] => Array ( [0] =>
This is P1
) ) [1] => Array ( [blockName] => [attrs] => Array ( ) [innerBlocks] => Array ( ) [innerHTML] => [innerContent] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [2] => Array ( [blockName] => core/paragraph [attrs] => Array ( ) [innerBlocks] => Array ( ) [innerHTML] =>
This is P2
[innerContent] => Array ( [0] =>
This is P2
) ) [3] => Array ( [blockName] => [attrs] => Array ( ) [innerBlocks] => Array ( ) [innerHTML] => [innerContent] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [4] => Array ( [blockName] => core/paragraph [attrs] => Array ( ) [innerBlocks] => Array ( ) [innerHTML] =>
This is P3
[innerContent] => Array ( [0] =>
This is P3
) ) [5] => Array ( [blockName] => [attrs] => Array ( ) [innerBlocks] => Array ( ) [innerHTML] => [innerContent] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [6] => Array ( [blockName] => core/paragraph [attrs] => Array ( ) [innerBlocks] => Array ( ) [innerHTML] =>
This is P4
[innerContent] => Array ( [0] =>
This is P4
) ) )
```

How would I place The innerContent of P3 in a template?

```
echo $blocks[3]
```

I have some wpdatatable blocks and I can show them like this:

```
<?php 
    $blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content() );
    foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
        if ( 'wpdatatables/wpdatatables-gutenberg-block' === $block['blockName'] ) {
            echo do_shortcode( $block['innerHTML'] );
            break;
         }
      }
?>
```

but can't access specific content blocks other than 'get_the_content()'

Am I misunderstanding how to use these? Is it possible to target by giving it a class name or ID somehow? Or just the array order?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Stupidly simple. It's just an array. Got caught up in all the Gutenberg stuff.

```
$blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content() );
echo($blocks[4]['innerHTML']);
```